# Will MonoTouch install on Apple iPad 2?

Tags: xamarin.ios, ipad-2

Will MonoTouch install on Apple iPad 2?

Comment: according to this tweet, it does https://twitter.com/kangamono/status/46384164701868032
Also see http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Apr-06.html

Answer (score 6):

MonoTouch doesn't get installed anywhere, it's a development environment.

Apps created with MonoTouch, on the other hand, can run in any iOS device, including the iPad 2.